# google fitBounds does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a click on a marker to zoom in, but one of the markers is not working correctly, it throws me outside the map, why is this happening?

```
  const center = { lng: 10.146871273903532, lat: 45.910759235732826 }
  const radius = 54.58294810993587
  const newRectangle = [
    {
      y: center.lat - radius,
      x: center.lng - radius,
    },
    {
      y: center.lat + radius,
      x: center.lng + radius,
    }
  ]

  const bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  newRectangle.forEach((item) => {
    console.log('getNewBounds -> item.y, item.x', item.y, item.x)
    bounds.extend(new window.google.maps.LatLng(item.y, item.x));
  });

  console.log('getNewBounds -> bounds', bounds)

  refs.map.fitBounds(bounds)
```

and i get in console.log

```
getNewBounds -> item.y, item.x -8.67218887420318 -44.436076836032434
getNewBounds -> item.y, item.x 100.49370734566855 64.7298193838393

getNewBounds -> bounds {
  Va: qf {i: -44.436076836032434, j: 64.7298193838393}
  Za: uf {i: -8.67218887420318, j: 90}
}
```

Comment: The maximum value of latitude (`y`) is 90 degrees.  What is "getNewBounds"?  Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue?  The posted code contains syntax errors.

Comment: @geocodezip Yes, I know that the maximum y (lat) is 90, the bounds.extend method itself cuts to 90, you can see this in getNewBounds -> bounds.Za.j